# How to change text of items in a searchable spinner

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

i am trying to create a searchable spinner and attach an array adapter to it. the content of the spinner should be an object (i did this so i can retrieve the id and display the name). I'm almost done but instead of the names getting displayed, I get this:
[searchable spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev6tg.png)

here's my code:

```
public class CitySpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<City> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<City> myObjs;

public CitySpinnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                              ArrayList<City> myObjs) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, myObjs);
    this.context = context;
    this.myObjs = myObjs;
}

public int getCount(){
    return myObjs.size();
}

public City getItem(int position){
    return myObjs.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position){
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView label = new TextView(context);
    label.setText(myObjs.get(position).getName());
    return label;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView label = new TextView(context);
    label.setText(myObjs.get(position).getName());
    return label;
}}
```

and here's how i created my spinner:

```
city2Spinner = (SearchableSpinner) findViewById(R.id.city2);

    CityDBHelper citydb = new CityDBHelper(getApplicationContext());

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> cities2 = citydb.getCities();

    cities2Obj = new ArrayList<City>();
    for(HashMap<String, String> city2 : cities2){
        //for(String key : province.keySet()){
        //String name = province.get(key);
        cities2Obj.add(new City(Integer.valueOf(city2.get("id")), Integer.valueOf(city2.get("orig_id")), city2.get("name"), Integer.valueOf(city2.get("pid"))));
        //}
    }

    CitySpinnerAdapter city2Adapter =
            new CitySpinnerAdapter(AddProspectActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cities2Obj);
    //adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    city2Spinner.setTitle("Select City");
    city2Spinner.setPositiveButton("OK");


    city2Spinner.setAdapter(city2Adapter);
```

i'm really confused as to where i should change the items. please help. i hope i was clear. :( (i am using com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. The solution is to make your `City` class override the `toString()` method. i have just added the code to create the adapter for clarity.

```
public String toString(){
     return name;
}
```

An Adapter example:

```
List<City> cities = ... ;
// Initializing an ArrayAdapter
citySpinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_item, cities);
    citySpinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
    citySpinner.setAdapter(citySpinnerArrayAdapter);
    // setTitle and setPositiveButton
    citySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
         //...

    });
```

Comment: thank you so much. :) i would love to upvote you but i dont have that much  privilege.. :(

Comment: Happy i contributed to helping in return for the valuable help i have received from SO.